# Warning: The type parameter E is hiding the type E when using an inner class

Tags: java, generics, static

I was writing a stack, one with a static Node and other non-static.

```
public class Stack<E> implements Iterable<E>
{
    private int N;
    private Node<E> first;

    private static class Node<E>    // This works fine.
    {
        private E item;
        private Node<E> next;
    }
}
```

But when I try to make the Node non-static, it gives me this warning "The type parameter E is hiding the type E"

```
public class Stack<E> implements Iterable<E>
{
    private int N;
    private Node<E> first;

    private class Node<E>    // This shows warning.
    {
        private E item;
        private Node<E> next;
    }
}
```

A bit of understanding which I have tell me that since static memeber is a member of class so it does not give me a warning but when I make it non-static it belongs to the instance. But its not a clear thought.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's warning you that you are using the generic argument name `E` in a scope when it already is defined.  Changing the generic argument name for `Node` would be one way to resolve the warning:

```
public class Stack<E> implements Iterable<E>
{
    private int N;
    private Node<E> first;

    private class Node<T>
    {
        private T item;
        private Node<T> next;
    }
}
```

But since E is already exists, you should just use that; `Node` is already generic due to being defined within a generic type (`Stack<object>.Node` and `Stack<String>.Node` are different types):

```
public class Stack<E> implements Iterable<E>
{
    private int N;
    private Node first;

    private class Node
    {
        private E item;
        private Node next;
    }
}
```

Note that this works because `Node` is not static, therefore it has a reference to the outer `Stack<E>` object, and because of this `E` must be defined.  If `Node` is static then it has no real relationship to the outer `Stack<E>` type other than effectively being within its lexical scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So when the Node is static it does not show me that error because it belongs to the class?Is it correct?

Comment: Also can you please elaborate more on why I dont need to make the Node generic?

Comment: @Vwin I've added an explanation.

Comment: Great. Thanks :) Why do you say "it has no real relationship"?

Comment: @Vwin If it's a static class then instances stand alone; if it's not a static class, instances can only stand with a relationship to an instance of the outer class.

Comment: Oh i see what you are saying. Thanks :)